# Is the ValidationResult class suitable when validating the state of an object?

Tags: c#, winforms, validation

I have a C# WinForms application where multiple objects in a collection need to be valid before functions can be called in each object.

I have done some research and there is a ValidationResult class. Is this class suitable for returning validation data about an object, such as some properties are null, or is there another specific class that should be used?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`RequiredAttribute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.requiredattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) from the [`System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) namespace. Put this attribute on top of a property to validate if it's not null like so:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
public class MyDto
{
    [Required]
    public SomeObject SomeProperty { get; set; }
}
```

Likewise you can use [more validation attributes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.validationattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) from this namespace.

You can also create your own validation attributes if you inherit from [`ValidationAttribute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.validationattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). For example a Validation attribute that validates every object inside a list, something like:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Parameter | AttributeTargets.Field | AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple = false)]
    public class ValidateCollectionAttribute : ValidationAttribute
    {
        protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
        {
            var collection = value as IEnumerable;

            if (collection != null)
            {
                foreach (object element in collection)
                {
                    //do validation
                }
            }

            return ValidationResult.Success;
        }
    }
```

Next you can use the [`Validator`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.validator%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class to validate your object. You need to create a ValidationContext where you put your instance into, like so:

```
var instance = new MyDto { SomeProperty = null }; //note that I'm setting the property to null, while the property has the Required attribute
var context = new ValidationContext(instance);
var validationResults = new List<ValidationResult>(); //this list will contain all validation results
Validator.TryValidateObject(instance, context, validationResults, validateAllProperties: true);
var errors = validationResults.Where(r => r != ValidationResult.Success); //filter out all successful results since we are only interested in errors
if (errors.Any())
{
    //do whatever you like to do
}
```

Since I've instantiated the `MyDto` object with `null` for it's property, the `Validator` will return a `ValidationResult` that's been triggered by the `Required` attribute.

You could create a service that executes this kind of code, or you could just hard-wire this inside your code-behind. Whatever floats your boat.